# Wordpress - The ssh2 PHP extension is not available

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, libssh2

I use SSH keys in my wp-config since a long time. Updates, plugin installation and removal, all worked well. After the last apt-get update wp is asking for the FTP password when I try to install for example a plugin.
There was no change done to the wp installation nor the file or directory permissions. I did not update wp either.

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','wp-user'); define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

Ubuntu 14.04
WORDPRESS VERSION: 4.7.6

PHP VERSION: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22

WEB SERVER INFO: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f
[image]

EDIT:

I added below to my wp-config to see if it changes something.

> define('FS_METHOD', 'ssh2');

No I'm getting a different error message in the WP backend:
**The ssh2 PHP extension is not available**

...but ssh2 is installed and loaded:

```
# php -m |grep ssh2
ssh2
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in libssh2-php...
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-ssh2/+bug/1617294

Installing the WP plugin below allows me again to install/update as before.

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/#description